# Volume Control Rate

Tags: gnome, 18.04, media-buttons

I have volume control buttons on my keyboard. Each click moves the volume about 5%. I would like it to only move 1%. I have a Logitech G810, so the volume control acts more like a scroll wheel and it's very easy to overshoot.

Answer (score 3):

Try hitting your volume control buttons while shift is pressed. This will adjust the volume in smaller increments.

Comment: Interesting, very good info @vanadium! Do you know if these steps ("how much to increment") are configurable somehow? As the original author, I have a volume wheel on my (Das Keyboard) keyboard and I would very much like to make the Shift-volume increase be the _default_ and not the other way around...

(Using Gnome 3.28 on Debian btw.)

Comment: Not sure about the backend, but commands such as `pactl set-sink-volume 0 +5%` allow to change the volume from the command line. Such a command may then be bound to your volume key.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I would like to change the built-in behavior though, but maybe it's simply not easily doable (or at least we don't know how).